# python debugging- get execution time for each line within a loop

Tags: python, performance, debugging, pycharm

In my code, the execution time of my for loop is increasing by roughly 1 second after roughly 1000 iteration. So, I am suspecting, there is something wrong within my for loop. I have break point after 1000 iteration, but i need to know which line is taking more time. use of `time.time()` while line-by-line debugging is certainly not a good idea. I could have used `timeit` to get the exact execution time for a block of code but it also not a good idea for my case, because i need to get the execution time of each line within a for loop, but not the whole loop. In this case what should i do? I am using **pycharm** for debugging. is there any option in this editor?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you profile a python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582336/how-can-you-profile-a-python-script)

Answer (score 2):

If you're using professional version of PyCharm, you can use builtin [profiler](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/profiler.html).

Otherwise, refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582336/how-can-you-profile-a-python-script).
Alternatively, you can have a look at [line_profiler](https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler).

Comment: Just run the program with pycharm's default cProfiler, but i can not sees anything that say excution time for a line.

Comment: On statistics page you can see what caused most load: how much time it was called and for how long. Otherwise, have a look at [line_profiler](https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler) or [memory_profiler](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/memory_profiler).